# XAML HorizontalAlignment property not doing what I want

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

xaml code, inside a grid:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
     <TextBlock Text="My text: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
     <TextBox Text="{Binding ...}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I would like the textblock to be left-aligned and the Tetblock to be right aligned. With the previous code, both are right-aligned.

Same result if I add an inner StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="My text: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
     </StackPanel>
     <TextBox  Text="{Binding ...}" />
</StackPanel>
```

How should I do?
Thx in advance.

Comment: `StackPanel` is a wrong control. Its `Children` are located one after another. Try to give `StackPanel` something distinct (e.g. `Background="Green"`) to see this. You probably want to use `Grid`. Its not clear why do you align `StackPanel` to the right, `Stretch` may do what you want, but you have another issue which you tried to solve by aligning it to the right, which one?

Comment: @Sinatr My guess was that he wanted the text to align at first, but then I realized he likely wants the `StackPanel` to fill the `Gird` cell and that the `TextBlock` should just fill up the remaining space. If that's so, a `DockPanel` will do the trick as that can use the last control to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use <del>`HorizontalContentAlignment`</del>`TextAlignment`. `HorizontalAlignment` defines the alignment of the `TextBox` relative to the `StackPanel`. The text inside the `TextBox` is still aligned by default to the left unless you have a global `Style` applied.

Also a `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation always uses the minimum space possible. So it will stack the controls as tightly as possible. You either have to use a grid or give the `TextBox`/`TextBlock` control a fixed width if you want to format it properly.

/edit: sorry. `TextAlignment` for a `TextBox` or `TextBlock` control. `HorizontalContentAlignment`is for controls that do not explicitly use a `Text` property like a `Label` for example.

An alternative if you do not want to use fixed width would be a Dockpanel like the following:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10, 0" LastChildFill="true">
    <TextBox   Width="160" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Right" BorderBrush="#6593CF" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding ...}" />
    <TextBlock Text="My text: " FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Left" />
</DockPanel>
```