# Stretching textblock and texbox in stackpannel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i want to auto stretching elements horizontally to grid width, so when you stretch window elements must proportionally stretched with it.

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,40" Name="TaskGrid" Visibility="Hidden">
    <StackPanel Name="AmountOfSP" Visibility="Collapsed" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <CheckBox   Name="restrRadioButton" Checked="restrCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="restrCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
       <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="bla-bla" />
       <TextBox Name="AmountOfO" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="70" Height="20" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: UniformGrid works good, some more problems, im using stacking fields by making visible of collapsed fields, how can i bind width of window to visible fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one more option along with the mentioned answer.  You can also make use of `UniformGrid` to achieve what you want.

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,40" Name="TaskGrid">
    <UniformGrid Name="AmountOfSP" Columns="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <CheckBox   x:Name="restrRadioButton"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="bla-bla" />
        <TextBox Name="AmountOfO" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="70" Height="20" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006686/xaml-horizontalalignment-property-not-doing-what-i-want/37006727#37006727) you can't use a `StackPanel` to strech in the stacking direction, because it will always use the smallest possible size for the stacking elements (unless they have a fixed size, then it will utilize that).

Use a `DockPanel` or `Grid` instead and order the inner components appropriately to stretch to the full size.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your stackpanel with a grid similar to the one shown below;

```
     <Grid Name="AmountOfSP" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <CheckBox   Name="restrRadioButton" Grid.Column="0" Checked="restrCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="restrCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="bla-bla" />
             <TextBox  Grid.Column="2" Name="AmountOfO" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="70" Height="20" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    <Grid>
```

You can play around with widths of your different controls by changing the columnDefinition widths e.g.

```
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
```

As it stands all three of your columns will have the same width and will expand to fill the control it occupies.

You cannot use as stack panel in this way because it literally just gets it's width/height by "stacking" (adding) the widths/heights of the controls it contains.

You may find work-arounds using the stack panel but it is much easier just to use a different control meant to do the job you are after.